# Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]' with an argument of type 'String'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I'm updating my app for iOS 13 / Swift 5 and ran into this error. I'm not 100% sure how to fix it. Any ideas?

```
@objc override open var tintColor: UIColor? {
    didSet {

        #if swift(>=4.2)
        var textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]()
        let foregroundColorKey = NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor
        #elseif swift(>=4)
        var textAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]()
        let foregroundColorKey = NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor
        #else
        var textAttributes = [String:Any]()
        let foregroundColorKey = NSForegroundColorAttributeName
        #endif

        textAttributes[foregroundColorKey] = tintColor

        #if swift(>=4)

            if let attributes = convertFromOptionalNSAttributedStringKeyDictionary(titleTextAttributes(for: .normal)) {

                for (key, value) in attributes {
                    #if swift(>=4.2)
                    textAttributes[key] = value
                    #else
                    textAttributes[NSAttributedStringKey.init(key)] = value
                    #endif
                }
            }

        #else

            if let attributes = titleTextAttributes(for: .normal) {
                textAttributes = attributes
            }
        #endif

        setTitleTextAttributes(textAttributes, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

The error its throwing is this:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type '[NSAttributedString.Key : Any]' with an argument of type 'String'
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you using all of those Swift version checks? Do you really need to compile this code under so many different versions of Swift?

Comment: updated the code so you can see the full picture.

Comment: What is the return type of the `convertFromOptionalNSAttributedStringKeyDictionary` function? Can you include it?

Comment: Updated with a declaration

Answer (score 0):

When you subscript `textAttributes` inside of your Swift 4.2 version check you are using `key` which is of type `String`. You want to initialize `NSAttributedString.Key` using `key` before subscripting `textAttributes`. So instead of:

```
textAttributes[key] = value
```

you want to do:

```
textAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key(key)] = value
```